# Can't scrape category titles from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've written a scraper in python to get different category names from a webpage but it is unable to fetch anything from that page. I'm seriously confused not to be able to figure out where i'm going wrong. Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Here is the link to the webpage: [URL](https://www.therange.co.uk/)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("replace_with_above_url",headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select('.slide_container .h3.standardTitle'):
    print(items.text)
```

Elements within which one such category names I'm after:

```
<div class="slide_container">
    <a href="/offers/furniture/" tabindex="0">
        <picture style="float: left; width: 100%;"><img style="width:100%" src="/_m4/9/8/1513184943_4413.jpg" data-w="270"></picture>
        <div class="floated-details inverted" style="height: 69px;">
            <div class="h3 margin-top-sm margin-bottom-sm standardTitle">
                Furniture Offers                         #This is the name I'm after
            </div>
            <p class="carouselDesc">
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting the right html in res.text?

Comment: It seem that server doesn't want you to scrape the data :) Your request returns you not the page you actually see in your browser, but block-page with the following content `"As you were browsing www.therange.co.uk something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen..."`

Comment: Tried with selenium but the end result is as you have mentioned @sir Andersson.

Comment: One more thing: as you are getting the same response what I'm getting so the blocking process is not meant to my IP address only;rather, it is applicable for all.

Comment: For me it works fine with Selenium... Did you try Headless PhantomJS browser?

Comment: Nope sir. I never thought that headless browser can be an option.

Comment: Oh, yep... It worked for me just 1 time with Chromedriver and 2 times with IE... and now I get the same block-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control':'max-age=0',
'referer':'https://www.therange.co.uk/',
'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
}
res = requests.get("https://www.therange.co.uk/",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
for items in soup.select('.slide_container .h3.standardTitle'):
    print(items.text)
```

Try this

> a user-agent is not enough because headers are the most important part
>   of scrapping.if you miss any header then server ll treat you as a bot.

Comment: You are just awesome @Tailor Devendra. Your solution worked finally. Gonna accept it  in a  while. I would like to know something though. You skipped few parameters along with cookies to add to the headers according to what i can see in the devtools. Moreover, you have added an extra parameter `referer` in the header. Could you please tell my why so that i can take into consideration in future. Thanks. Again, your solution did the trick flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`"html.parser"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) instead of `"lxml"`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

Comment: I assumed the variable`res.text` contains the above html and calculated further. Can you paste the html you are getting in `res.text`?